# Jquery scroll на нужной странице

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет! Есть код который средствами ajax получает данные из бд при скролле, как сделать так чтобы данные код работал только на одной странице сайта, то есть на которой мне нужно. Сейчас код работает на всех страницах. Всем спасибо!
Вот код:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var inProgress = false;
  var startFrom = 9;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() - 300 && !inProgress) {
      $.ajax({
        url: '/test/load',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
          'startFrom': startFrom
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
          inProgress = true;
        }

      }).done(function(data) {
        data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        if (data.lenght > 0) {
          $.each(data, function(index, data) {
            $('.row').append('<p>' + data.name + '</p>' + '<p>' + data.title + '</p>');
          });
          inProgress = false;
          startFrom += 9;
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: вместо.row использовуйте class, которого нет на других страницах, или подключить данный скрипт только на необходимой странице

Comment: soledar10 Спасибо! Пока подключил на нужную страницу, будем думать дальше..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант повешать на тэг body id и проверять при запуске скрипта наличие этого id.

Или еще вариант, топорный, но сработает:

```
if(window.location.href == 'http://host-ru/'){
  $(window).scroll(function() { ... }
}
```

Comment: Станислав Усанов пробовал, при скролле редирект постоянный

Comment: а если так: window.location.href

Comment: Станислав Усанов не понял, имеется ввиду без пути?

Comment: [матчасть на русском ;)](https://javascript.ru/window-location)

Comment: Станислав Усанов Спасибо! Забыл указать условие))